# Flask. Как входить на сайт не через ip адрес и порт, а через, например mysite.com

Tags: python, flask, backend

Как входить на сайт Flask через какое-нибудь, например, mysite.com, вместо ip?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: @Духсообщества ну, например, я захожу на сайт вводя в url ip адрес и порт 127.0.0.1. Как входить, вводя туда mysite.com и т.п. вместо обычного ip

Comment: Это называется DNS. Либо вы покупаете доменное имя, либо используете бесплатное из разряда FreeDNS. Где вообще этот Flask крутится? 127.0.0.1 - это локальный IP, его снаружи не видно. Вы откуда хотите по имени ходить? Если от себя, то у себя и пропишите резолв красивого имени в 127.0.0.1 в localhosts каком-нибудь. А если снаружи, то см. выше и ещё надо через раутер как-то пробросить реальный ip на этот ваш локальный адрес будет.

Comment: @Духсообщества у себя. не снаружи

Comment: Тогда самое простое это `/etc/hosts`. В винде где-то тут `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`